# Image Source bound to missing file

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding

How can I display a default image when the bound path file is missing?

```
<Image  Source="{Binding DisplayedBook.ImagePath}" />
```

---

My solution: Used a converter, which check if the image exists and returns the appropriate path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you don't want to return default image from `ImagePath` getter, than another approach is to return null.

```
public string ImagePath
{
   get
   {
     return File.Exists(m_Path) ? m_Path : null;
   }
}
```

and in XAML use TargetNullValue property of Binding

```
<Image  Source="{Binding DisplayedBook.ImagePath, TargetNullValue={StaticResource SomeImageResource}}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have code-behind associated with this XAML (i.e. not a Template) you can set a default image on the ImageFailed event:

```
<Image  Source="{Binding ImagePath}" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" />
```

and the handler:

```
    private void Image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        if (image != null)
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://SomeDefaultImagePath.jpg"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don' use wpf, so i don't know if there exists such a special feature.

But i would implement such a thing in the getter method of `DisplayedBook.ImagePath`. It checks if the file exists and if not return a path to some default image.

Comment: i thought about it, problem is it couples the book entity with UI. And the book can't know what is the default image.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this:

Get the path of the image in path.

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

    image.BeginInit();
    image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    image.DecodePixelWidth = Convert.ToInt32(img.Width);
    image.EndInit();

    //Set the image corresponding to that bound
    this.img.Source = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the `FallbackValue` property which Gets or sets the value to use when the binding is unable to return a value.